# What is the technique called where all emails with some prefix go to a single mailbox

Tags: email, email-address, email-accounts

I have an issue where I need multiple emails to go to a single mailbox and it needs to be done on the fly without setting up new emails. For instance, the following three emails would all go to the same mailbox. This would allow for unique email addresses that are created on the fly (unique email constraint in the database) but the email would go to an account that all developers and testers are monitoring.

- `test-johnsmith@mysite.com`
- `test-jamesbrown@mysite.com`
- `test-janedoe@mysite.com`

By putting "test" (replace with a more unique value) on the email address it would signify to the mail server that it goes to mailbox `testingaccounts`.

1. Do you know what this technique is called?
2. Do you know how to do this with exchange?

I am not sure if this is in the correct sub forum but with out an "Exchange Administrators" I could not be sure.  Also the colleague from a few years ago that told me about this technique was a webmaster.

Comment: This is an e-mail address *alias*. I do not know how to set this up on Exchange. Sorry. For the record, on my system, I only ever use aliases. No exceptions! That way I do not have to go through the pain of changing an e-mail address. I give out aliases one per person or company. Ask me for an e-mail? You get a brand new alias every time. If anything goes wrong, all I have to do is remove the alias and possibly create another alias - depending upon what happened. It is a great anti-spam method. Cheers!!

Comment: Dan, you may be referring to a so called 'catch-all' e-mail process. That is usually an option provided by a hosting account for a particular domain name. I am not familiar with Exchange Server so I cannot advise on that.

Comment: We use alias now but they have to be setup in the beginning.  I am looking to just have something that will send all test*@mysite.com addresses go to devsupport@mysite.com type setup.  That way devs and testers can set up and email on the fly.

Comment: Can you use free linux/unix smtp server?  Sendmail/postfix/exim can redirect messages addressed to `anything@test.mysite.com` to test@mysite.com

Comment: If you want to capture unknown or e-mail of a pattern, that would be a catch-all address. I used Exchange as a second filter after GFI for my e-mail gateway when I was an web host. I still used aliases, but also set-up a catch-all account to capture anything that would fall through the cracks. That was a long time ago, so I am sure I cannot help. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean a catch-all inbox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-all

You can make rules like:

```
*@example.net -> all@example.net
```

I'm not an exchange expert, but i think this will help: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691132(v=exchg.80).aspx

As described you can define a pattern as transportrule, like:

```
^brian@contoso.com$
```